# Volume between paraboloid and sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume, multiple-integral

I need to find the volume between a parabola and a sphere given by $2-2x^2-2y^2=z$ for the paraboloid and $z \ge 2-2x^2-2y^2$, $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ for the sphere.

The intersection point between the sphere and parabola finds place at $z=\frac{1}{2}$ therefore $\frac{1}{2} \le z \le 2$. This is where I think I made my mistake, at finding my interval for $r$

I got $r^2=1-z^2$ for the equation of the paraboloid and $r^2=\frac{2-z}{2}$ for the equation of the sphere

therefore $\sqrt{1-z^2}\le r\le \sqrt{\frac{2-z}{2}}$

for theta I got $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$

Now the integral, which gave me the wrong answer

$$\int _{\frac{1}{2}}^2\int _0^{2\pi }\int _{\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{\frac{2-z}{2}}}rdrd\theta dz = \frac{27}{16}\pi$$

Comment: First, you mean *paraboloid*. Second, the real issue is what the problem is asking for. The paraboloid and the sphere intersect at *both* $z=0$ and $z=1/2$. So there are two regions "between" the two surfaces: above the sphere and under the paraboloid (as you considered), or inside the sphere and outside the paraboloid (so $0\le z\le 1/2$). The person who wrote the problem needs to specify what he/she is looking for.

Comment: I forgot to mention $z\ge 2-2x^2-2y^2$

Comment: So which of the two regions I described is relevant? (In your edit, you stuck the inequality where it does not make sense. Take the time to rewrite the problem carefully and correctly.)

Comment: I find that when computing a solid of revolution it often pays to draw a cross-section through the axis of revolution. In the cross-section you just have a parabola and a circle, which are easier to plot than a paraboloid and a sphere. You also have information about which side if the parabola the area of integration lies on, so you can use that in the drawing of the cross-section.

Comment: What's the correct answer?

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{48}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach using usual multiple integrals not using the disk method for anyone interested:

We have $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $z \leq 2 - 2(x^2+y^2)$ so $z \leq 2 - 2(1-z^2) \implies 2z^2+z \leq 0$ which means $0 \leq z \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Leveraging symmetry, we transition to cylindrical coordinates $(x,y,z) \mapsto (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, z)$. $\theta$ limits are standard $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. $r$ limits are a bit tricky. You notice that between $0 \leq z \leq \frac{1}{2}$, the parabola is inside the sphere, so the $r$ is bounded below by the parabola and bounded above by the sphere. So $\sqrt{1 - \frac{z}{2}}\leq r \leq \sqrt{1 - z^{2}}$ (since that's the region between $r^2+z^2\leq 1$ and $z+2r^2 \geq 2$ i.e between the parabola and the sphere). So the integral becomes:

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{2 \pi}\int\limits_{\sqrt{1 - \frac{z}{2}}}^{\sqrt{1 - z^{2}}} r\, dr\, d\theta\, dz = \frac{\pi}{48}$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I see where I messed up..

Answer (score 1):

Given $z \ge 2-2x^2-2y^2$, the integration range for $z$ is $0\le z\le \frac 12$. With the disk method, the enclosed volume is
\begin{align}
V= \int_{0}^{\frac12} \pi( r_2^2-r_1^2)dz
= \pi \int_{0}^{\frac12}
\left[(1-z^2)-(1-\frac12z)\right]dz=\frac\pi{48}
\end{align}